# Namespace references in C# vs. VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, using, using-directives

In VB.Net you can do something like the following without any issues... just ignore the fact that this is a pretty useless class :-)

```
Imports System

Public Class Class1
    Public Shared Function ArrayToList(ByVal _array() As String) As Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
        Return New Collections.Generic.List(Of String)(_array)
    End Function
End Class
```

However if you do the same thing in C#...

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
    public static Collections.Generic.List ArrayToList(string[] _array)
    {
        return new Collections.Generic.List(_array);
    }
}
```

You will get an error on the line with the return on "Collections.Generic.List" saying "The type or namespace name 'Collections' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I know that you have to actually have a using directive to System.Collections.Generic to use List but I don't know *why*.  I also don't understand why I don't get the same error in the function declaration, but only in the return statement.

I was hoping someone can explain this or even refer me to a technet page that explains it.  I have searched around, but can't find anything that explains this concept.

Edit: Just to note, the question is really about the referencing of a sub-namespace such as in the example being able to reference Collections within System.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768905/namespace-and-sub-namespaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` directive in C# [does not allow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(VS.80,loband).aspx) this:

> Create a using directive to use the
>   types in a namespace without having to
>   specify the namespace. A using
>   directive does not give you access to
>   any namespaces that are nested in the
>   namespace you specify.

VB.NET, however, [supports somewhat closer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x(VS.71,loband).aspx) behavior with `Imports` statement:

> The scope of the elements made
>   available by an Imports statement
>   depends on how specific you are when
>   using the Imports statement. For
>   example, if only a namespace is
>   specified, all uniquely named members
>   of that namespace, and members of
>   modules within that namespace, are
>   available without qualification. If
>   both a namespace and the name of an
>   element of that namespace are
>   specified, only the members of that
>   element are available without
>   qualification.

[Reference SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768905/namespace-and-sub-namespaces/768939#768939)

Comment: This is awesome, not sure how I missed this post, I guess my search string just wasn't close enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is because **VB.Net supports partial namespaces**; C# does not.

> With Visual Basic, System is imported
>   by default and child namespaces are
>   automatically resolved.

Read more in this article.

[VB.Net vs C#, Round 2: Partial Namespaces](http://jcoehoorn.vox.com/library/post/vbnet-vs-c-round-2-partial-namespaces.html)

Comment: That's an awesome article.  The third post I think answers the question most directly here, but this was very helpful so I gave the points.  Thanks!

Comment: @rahul, the link to the partial namespaces article is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

you can say System.Collections.Generic.List. that would work.

I think you need to give the entire list and not omit out the system part.

ALso you will need to template it with string as in List similar to the List(Of string)