# VB.NET namespace abbreviation: How do I make this work in equivalent C# code?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using-directives, vb.net-to-c#

I am a VB.NET programmer by nature and I am having a hard time figuring this out. Any help with the following would be appreciated.

I need to get the C# code (1) below to work. The VB.NET equivalent works just fine, but the C# does not.

Note that both (2) and (3) do work, but this is actually auto-generated code, and I need the VB.NET and C# versions to be as similar as possible.

1. This does not compile (the fully-qualified name of `Engine` is `ThreeD.QVB.Engine`):

   ```
   using ThreeD.QVB;

   namespace QVBScript
   {
       public class ScriptCode
       {
           public void Main(ref Engine.QVBObjectsDictionary objects,
                            Engine.Commands commands)
           {
               …
   ```
2. However, this *does* work:

   ```
   //using ThreeD.QVB; // I'm instead using fully-qualified names in the method

   namespace QVBScript
   {
       public class ScriptCode
       {
           public void Main(ref ThreeD.QVB.Engine.QVBObjectsDictionary objects,
                           ThreeD.QVB.Engine.Commands commands)
           {
               …
   ```
3. This works, too:

   ```
   using eng = ThreeD.QVB.Engine;

   namespace QVBScript
   {
       public class ScriptCode
       {
           public void Main(ref eng.QVBObjectsDictionary objects, 
                            eng.Commands commands)
           {
               …
   ```

Comment: Is `ThreeD.QVB.Engine` a namespace containing a type called `QVBObjectsDictionary`, or a type with a nested type? A short but *complete* example would really help.

Comment: Also, what specific error message are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315256/namespace-references-in-c-sharp-vs-vb-net

Comment: Assuming that you already add reference to it.  Try to remove "using ThreeD.QVB;" from 1.  and then go to Engine.QVBObjectsDictionary right click and select resolve and see what using statement is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.NET if you have an `import` for the first part of a namespace, you can reference just the later half.  In C# you cannot do this.  You must have a `using` for the full namespace, or fully qualify your type names.  Different languages, different rules.

In your last example you do not need to use the alias.

```
using ThreeD.QVB.Engine;

namespace QVBScript
{
    public class ScriptCode
    {
        public void Main(ref QVBObjectsDictionary objects, Commands commands)
        {
            UI.Output Output = (UI.Output)objects["Output"];
```

Comment: Yep, this is the problem and the answer.  Not a C# person and trying to hand code the differences.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Basic rules to remember:

### `using A.B;`

- *does* allow you to refer to *types* from namespaces `A` and `A.B` without fully qualifying them with their namespace (everywhere in the same file).
- *does not* allow you to abbreviate the names of sub-*namespaces* of `A` or `A.B.` by omitting the `A.` or `A.B.` part from their names.

### `namespace A.B { … }`

- *does* allow you to refer to *types* from namespaces `A` and `A.B` without fully qualifying them with their namespace (inside the block).
- *does* allow you to abbreviate the names of sub-*namespaces* of `A` or `A.B` by omitting the `A.` or `A.B.` part from their names.

---

## Example:

```
using System.Collections;

namespace A
{
  class Top : IDisposable, // importing System.Collections also imports System   
              IEnumerable, // inside the imported namespace
              System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>
  {…}                      // ^ "using" does not permit namespace abbreviation
}

namespace A.B
{
  class Middle : Top,      // namespace A available inside namespace A.B
                 C.IBottom // namespace blocks permit namespace abbreviation
  {…}
}

namespace A.B.C
{
  interface IBottom {…}
}
```