# .NET Namespace sub directories

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have experience using packages in Java.  I am now using Namespaces in .NET.  I have read a few web pages online which compare namespaces and packages.

Say I have a package called: Test.TestProgram.  If I import Test then I can use TestProgram.  I am confused about what happens if you have a namespace called Test.Test.  If you import Test then it does not import all of the namespaces below.  Why is this?

This is a simple question and I though I would find my answer on MSDN.  I am yet to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered this question here: [Namespace and Sub Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768905/namespace-and-sub-namespaces).  There is a link to MSDN with an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Importing a namespace does give you access to everything in it, within the usual rules of course. If your namespace is split across multiple assemblies, your items are not public, or they are internal then you won't automatically have access to them. In cases like this you will have to take extra steps like referencing the additional assembly or declaring a friend assembly, or using reflection to get to the non public members.