# C# using NamesSpaces

Tags: c#, class, types, namespaces

```
File 1
namespace ivandro.ismael.gomes
{
    class MyClass1
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    }
}
File 2
namespace ivandro.ismael
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

Note: `MyClass` will be visible to `MyClass1` without saying using `ivandro.ismael` but if you say `using System.Text`, only the types in `System.Text` will be visible not the types inside the `System`
**Do you know why?!**

Comment: [Previous Jon Skeet answer that is related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/768921/1324033)

Comment: Since you currently have *no* `using` directives in your example, why do you then compare apples and oranges and try to compare to a different situation where you do apply a `using` directive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Namespace and Sub Namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768905/namespace-and-sub-namespaces)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because code inside a `namespace` block behaves differently than just putting a `using` statement. You could visualize your MyClass1 code like the following.

```
namespace ivandro
{   
    namepace ismael
    {
        namepsace gomes
        {    
             class MyClass1
             {
                 MyClass obj = new MyClass();
             }
        }           
    }
}
```

So when you are inside a namespace all of the levels leading up to that namespace are included also.

Comment: Hey Scott, is there any reference site to check how this work internally? I'm curious now to see the inner logic if there is any :P

Comment: I don't know off hand exactly where but it is listed [in the C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) somewhere.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it's because `namespace ivandro.ismael.gomes` is actually compiled as `namespace ivandro { namespace ismael { namespace gomes { ... } } }`. No need to visualize, because that mean the class in the scope of the inner namespace, is also in the scope of the outer namespace. I'll suggest you edit your answer.