# Where are the using statements in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

From all these years of exp, I feel weird.
My Console App within Program class and Main method looks like this.

```
namespace NRules.Samples.RuleBuilder
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var repository = new CustomRuleRepository();
            repository.LoadRules();

            ISessionFactory factory = repository.Compile();
            ISession session = factory.CreateSession();
        }
    }
}
```

Thats the content of entire Program.cs file.
The **ISessionFactory** and **ISession** live in NRules namespace and so
I am expecting a using statement without which this should not compile. But strangely this complies and runs as well.

What am I missing? Is it that since the namespace here is **NRules.Samples.RuleBuilder** and so Visual Studio 2013 does not need NRules again?
Also the tool tip correctly shows NRules.ISession when I hover over the interface line.

[image]

Comment: its in a parent namespace and and those are available without any `using` statements.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768905/namespace-and-sub-namespaces

Comment: Strange, I some how never realized this. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace `NRules.Samples.Rulebuilder` is actually this:

```
namespace NRules
{
    namespace Samples
    {
        namespace Rulebuilder
        {
            internal class Program {/*...*/}
        }
    }
}
```

since your class is within the `NRules` namespace, you don't need a `using` statement to import public members of `NRules`.